# Как сделать зацикливание pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Мне нужно рандомно от 1 до 27 нажать pyautogui.press('left')
я попробовал это сделать так

```py
for i in range[random.randint(1,27)]:
    pyautogui.press('left')
```

но выдаёт ошибку

```
'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Поставьте заместо квадратных скобок круглые скобки, вы ведь не передаете в цикл словарь или список

Comment: @MaximChyorny не работает( ошибки нету но он нажимает только один раз

Comment: Как вы узнали что один раз?

Comment: как бы я сделал это, и он нажимает один раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(random.randint(1, 27)):
    pyautogui.press('left')
```